# My Textbox does not change when inside Task.Run

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I use C# Winforms

I am using `Task.Run()` in order to get my WinForm does not freeze.

Inside this code, I need to update the textbox text.

I tried to update textbox text directly and through Invoke but non worked.

I tried to minimize my code to just focus on the problem

Any idea how to update the text box inside `Task.Run()`?

```
public async void MyFunction()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lvwFiles.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in this.lvwFiles.Items)
            {
                txtLog.Text = item.Text + "\r\n" +txtLog.Text;
                if (txtLog.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    txtLog.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { txtLog.Text = item.Text + "\r\n" + txtLog.Text; }));
                }
                Thread.Sleep(4000);

                item.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 128);
            }
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update the GUI from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread)

Comment: @JonathanBarraone this is the solution in my answer and does not work!

Comment: _”I am using Task.Run() in order to get my WinForm does not freeze”_ … ? … Why would the window freeze if you updated a text box?

Comment: @JohnG  "I tried to minimize my code to just focus on the problem" the WinForm freezes because it upload files to SFTP

Comment: Instead of using the `BeginInvoke` in order to update the UI from inside the `Task.Run` lambda, you could consider updating the UI after the `Task.Run` has completed. The result of the computation can be obtained by just awaiting the `Task.Run`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68052346/await-dispatcher-invokeasync-vs-dispatcher-invoke/68053609#68053609). Alternatively you could use a `Progress<string>` to report progress to the UI while the `Task.Run` is running, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker/64620920#64620920).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Task.Run` to run it in a different thread, but then you're using `BeginInvoke`, which tells it to run that code on the UI thread. So the result is that your code is run on the UI thread. And since you're using `Thread.Sleep()`, you lock your UI thread.

Instead, run it all on your UI thread and use [`Task.Delay()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) instead of `Thread.Sleep()` to avoid locking the UI thread.

```
public async void MyFunction()
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in this.lvwFiles.Items)
    {
        txtLog.Text = item.Text + "\r\n" + txtLog.Text;
        await Task.Delay(4000);

        item.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 128);
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to update a temp string in the loop and then only update the textbox once, when the loop has ended.

Comment: @PoulBak That's a good idea too, unless the goal is to see the textbox updated during the delay.