# How does C# decide which SyncronizationContext to check on whether an awaiter is completed

Tags: c#, async-await

In [this article](https://thomaslevesque.com/2015/11/11/explicitly-switch-to-the-ui-thread-in-an-async-method/), we can see there's a *SynchronizationContextAwaiter* implementation for C# runtime to check if `SynchronizationContext.Current` is desired one, this enable us to jump between threads when writing async methods.

My question is how does `SynchronizationContext.Current` change. Does *SynchronizationContext* rotates? Or does it get picked randomly?

EDIT: To be more specific, how does `IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext` gets executed by different `SynchronizationContext`?

Comment: foreground/background threads are a different concept than UI threads/non-UI threads. Be aware of the difference

Comment: @ThomasWeller Good point, I'll edit it to just "jump between threads".

Comment: Excellent read here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

Comment: Be aware that the technique presented in [the article](https://thomaslevesque.com/2015/11/11/explicitly-switch-to-the-ui-thread-in-an-async-method/) for offloading work to a background thread, is flawed. The `ConfigureAwait(false);` has no effect in case the awaitable is completed at the `await` point, so if the `Task` returned by the `GetDataFromRemoteServerAsync()` happens to complete very fast, it is theoretically possible that the `DoSomeCpuBoundWorkWithTheData(data);` **will run on the UI thread**. The correct and reliable way to offload work to the `ThreadPool` is the `Task.Run` method.

Comment: @Moho Yeah that's a good article, but it does not cover about how IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext is executed by different contexts.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks for the heads up, I'll keep that in mind. The question is more about to `move between threads`, so it won't be a problem if a context is specified (with an awaiter).

Comment: You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363413/why-was-switchto-removed-from-async-ctp-release "Why was “SwitchTo” removed from Async CTP / Release?") interesting. Some people like switching from context to context imperatively, most don't (or don't know that it's even possible).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I believe it's quite useful in Unity, which loops on magic methods with certain names.

Comment: This question is a little disjointed. What is it you are actually trying to achieve here, what problem are you trying to solve? It would be likely easier than than a deep dive into the internal plumbing of the async and await pattern

Comment: @TheGeneral I can already jump to desired thread with the SynchronizationContextAwaiter approach. But the question, `How does this works?` just occurs to me every now and then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does C# decide which SyncronizationContext to check on whether an awaiter is completed

[When code `await`s a task](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), it first checks whether the task is complete. If it's already complete, then the code continues executing synchronously past the `await`. Otherwise, by default `await` will capture the `SynchronizationContext.Current` at that time. This default behavior is prevented by using `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)`.

> this enable us to jump between threads when writing async methods.

True. But I don't recommend that style of code. IMO the code is more maintainable by using separate methods that each run in a specific context. Or if you don't want to use separate methods, at least split them up using delegates.

E.g., if you want to run code on a UI thread, it's cleaner to queue a method to run on that UI thread rather than have *one* method that is partially run on a background thread and partially run on a UI thread. This is especially true when considering error handling: if you have a `try` that is partially one thread and partially another, you also have to assume the `catch`/`finally` blocks can run in either of those contexts.

> My question is how does SynchronizationContext.Current change.

`SynchronizationContext.Current` can be set by any thread, but it's *usually* set by whatever queueing mechanism is executing code. E.g., UI threads get their `SynchronizationContext.Current` set when they enter their main loop (which includes their queue), i.e., `Dispatcher.Run` for WPF or `Application.Run` for WinForms.

> EDIT: To be more specific, how does IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext gets executed by different SynchronizationContext?

The `SynchronizationContext` is captured by the `TaskAwaiter`, and when the awaitable completes, it resumes executing the method by passing the continuation to `SynchronizationContext.Post` (unless it can execute it directly).

[All of this is open source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e4e942f91e6e2e32988a610c0e7f754df7df56b1/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs#L364), BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and yes I value good way of writing code, It's just that I believe this is useful in Unity. Not sure if I follow, does this answers the core question `how does IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext gets executed by different SynchronizationContext?`?  

About `when the awaitable completes`, AsyncStateMachine checks that by looking at the TaskAwaiter's `IsCompleted`, at this point, who is running it?

Comment: `IsCompleted` is executed by the same thread that was running before the `await`.

Comment: If that is true, I can't get my head around how is it possible to jump between threads by await until `SynchronizationContext.Current` is the desired one.

Comment: If `IsCompleted` is false, then the state machine schedules a continuation on the awaitable. This continuation is a `SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation`, which executes the continuation by passing it to `SynchronizationContext.Post`.

Comment: Oh my! I thought OnCompleted is executed when it is completed. Really should have pay more attention... Sorry for the bothering and thanks very much!