# Does .NET 6's PeriodicTimer capture the current SynchronizationContext by default?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, configureawait, periodictimer

For `PeriodicTimer` (`AsyncTimer` at the time), regarding `WaitForNextTickAsync`, David Fowler mentioned "The execution context isn't captured" ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31525)) via ([here](https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/08/net6-Threading/)).  However, given that was not necessarily the final implementation, I reviewed the `PeriodicTimer` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-6.0) which makes no mention of context capturing.

Based on Stephen Toub's decade old, but still excellent, "[The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=19957)," and the following code:

```
private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

private async void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var second = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    using var timer = new PeriodicTimer(second);

    try
    {
        while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(tokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (txtMessages.InvokeRequired)
            {
                txtMessages.Invoke(() => txtMessages.AppendText("Invoke Required..." + Environment.NewLine));
            }
            else
            {
                txtMessages.AppendText("Invoke NOT Required!" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    } catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        //disregard the cancellation
    }
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

If `ConfigureAwait` is passed `true` (or removed entirely), my output is as follows:

```
Invoke NOT Required!
Invoke NOT Required!
Invoke NOT Required!
Invoke NOT Required!
...
```

However, if `ConfigureAwait` is passed `false`, my output is as follows:

```
Invoke Required...
Invoke Required...
Invoke Required...
Invoke Required...
...
```

Unless I'm confusing `SynchronizationContext` with "executing thread," it seems like the current `SynchronizationContext` IS captured by default.  Can anyone (maybe one of the greats) please clarify?

Answer (score 2):

The new (.NET 6) `PeriodicTimer` component is not like all other `Timer` components that raise events or execute callbacks. This one resembles more the [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) method. It exposes a single asynchronous method, the method [`WaitForNextTickAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer.waitfornexttickasync). This method is not special in any way. It returns a standard `ValueTask<bool>`, not some kind of exotic awaitable like the [`Task.Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield) method (`YieldAwaitable`).

When you [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) this task, you control the `SynchronizationContext`-capturing behavior of the `await` like you do for any other `Task` or `ValueTask`: with the [`ConfigureAwait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1.configureawait) method. If you know how to use the `ConfigureAwait` with the `Task.Delay`, you also know how to use it with the `PeriodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync`. There is absolutely no difference.

If you don't know what the `ConfigureAwait` does, or you want to refresh your memory, there is a plethora of good articles to read. For the sake of variance I'll suggest this old 5-minute video by Lucian Wischik: [Tip 6: Async library methods should consider using `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/three-essential-tips-for-async/async-library-methods-should-consider-using-task-configureawait-false)

Comment: Thank you, @Theodor.  I think I understand what `ConfigureAwait` does, but was confused when my example code didn't seem to exhibit behavior that the `PeriodicTimer` (`AsyncTimer`) would not capture the current execution context by default.  I was previously using `await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);` properly I think.  I think it was perhaps your? response to another SO post that caused me to look at `PeriodicTimer` because `WaitForNextTickAsync` is more performant than `Task.Delay` due to the `ValueTask<bool>` return (vs. `Task`).

Comment: Yasss.  Found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval

Comment: @Novox actually it's more performant also because it creates [internally](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/32f5873a1d2d72722f29618fd9f1d5556dae8f65/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/PeriodicTimer.cs#L20) a single `TimerQueueTimer` instance, instead of creating a new `TimerQueueTimer` each time you use the `Task.Delay` method (the internal [`DelayPromise`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/32f5873a1d2d72722f29618fd9f1d5556dae8f65/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5604) class).

Comment: Thanks again, @Theodor.  All very good information, but do you know if the execution context is captured, by default, for `WaitForNextTickAsync`?  My investigation seems to indicate no.

Comment: @Novox TBH I don't know much about the `ExecutionContext`, because of this advice: *"ExecutionContext is one of those things that the vast majority of developers never need to think about."* from [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/ "ExecutionContext vs SynchronizationContext") article by Stephen Toub. The same article also says: *"ExecutionContext is flowed across await points regardless of what kind of awaitable is being used."*

Comment: I read that article, thank you.  I feel like the answer should be in there, somewhere, given it's titled, "ExecutionContext vs SynchronizationContext."  However, I only have more questions...  While I may not need to think about the `ExecutionContext`, I DO need to worry about the `SynchronizationContext`.  In my example code, the default behavior causes the `TextBox`'s `AppendText` to occur in the UI thread.  I don't necessarily want this because I want the UI to be as responsive as possible.  `ConfigureAwait(false)` seems to account for this, invoking `AppendText` in a non-UI thread.

Comment: Aside from their return types, as far as I can tell, `await Task.Delay(1000, tokenSource.Token)` and `timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(tokenSource.Token)` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Novox my suggestion is to avoid using the `ConfigureAwait` (or the `Task.Yield`) with the purpose of controlling the continuation thread. If you want to offload work to the `ThreadPool`, you can use the `Task.Run`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72738858/what-exactly-in-an-awaitable-is-being-awaited-how-do-i-make-a-task-properly/72739056#72739056) is a recent answer of mine, that offers a bit more context.

Comment: I tried running my try/catch code within `Task.Run(async () => { ... });`  Now, both cases (`ConfigureAwait` with `false` vs. `true` (or removed entirely)) indicate invocation is required.  However, this is expected since `Task.Run` is explicitly using a `ThreadPool` thread (not my  main UI thread).  Capturing the current `SynchronizationContext` (with `ConfigureAwait(true)` or removing the use of `ConfigureAwait`) *appears* to work the same as not-capturing (with `ConfigureAwait(false)`) because neither the current context nor a new context are my main UI thread (both requiring invocation).

Comment: @Novox if you want a specific behavior and have troubles producing it, you could ask a new question about your scenario, including expected and actual behavior. Most likely the solution will be something pretty simple. The simple solutions are the best solutions!