# Batch from yield don't start up concurrently

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, yield, concurrently

I'm currently trying to implement a file searcher that yields found files in batches so it can get processed concurrently. But my problem arrives when it yields and I pass it to a task. It never starts multiple tasks up, but waits for the previous task is done before starting next up, where I want it to start as many tasks up as my `SemaphoreSlim` is allowing. I'm new to yielding and are unsure if the problem is the yield because it waits until the previous yield iter is done even tho it gets passed to `Task.Run()`.

```
public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var index = 0;
    using var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(8, 16);
    foreach (var items in FileSearcher.EnumerateFilesRecursively(@"E:/nestedAAAA", batchSize, cancellationToken))
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            tasks.Add(StartTasksAsync(items, index, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                semaphore.Release();
                tasks.Remove(task);
            }));
            index++;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in HarvestEngine RunAsync");
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task StartTasksAsync(
    IEnumerable<string> items, 
    int index,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"[Task {index}] has started.....");

    var databaseService = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseService>();
    var collectedSensitiveFiles = new List<FileInformation>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{index} has found {item}");
    }
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    _logger.LogInformation($"[Task {index}] is done.....");
}
```

If I set `Task.Delay` to 10 sec, it will wait the 10 sec before the next task starts even tho the `Task.Delay` is inside my newly started task and should only make my new task sleep, and not do so it has to wait the desired amount before the next task can start up. so if i put 1 min, it will take 1 min before next starts up etc, which dosn't really make sense to me(Except if there is some yielding stuff I don't know).

This is how I yield my files found:

```
internal static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> EnumerateFilesRecursively(
    string directory, 
    int batchSize,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();
    List<string> currentFoundFiles = new List<string>();
    stack.Push(directory);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        string currentDir = stack.Pop();

        try
        {
            foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir))
                stack.Push(subDir);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            Log.Error("File Searcher: UnauthorizedAccessException");
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            Log.Error("File Searcher: UnauthorizedAccessException");

        }

        try
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(currentDir, "*")
                .Where(file => allowedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
                .ToList();

            currentFoundFiles.AddRange(files);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            Log.Error("File Searcher 2: UnauthorizedAccessException");
            continue;
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            Log.Error("File Searcher 2: UnauthorizedAccessException");
            continue;
        }

        if (currentFoundFiles.Count < batchSize) continue;
        yield return currentFoundFiles;
        currentFoundFiles.Clear();
    }

    if(!currentFoundFiles.IsNullOrEmpty())
        yield return currentFoundFiles;
}
```

** UPDATED **

So i have simplified it.
What puzzles is the foreach in my `Task.Run` only prints all items out on my last created tasks, and all previous tasks it only prints the first item in the `IEnumerable` collection

```
 public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     var tasks = new List<Task>();
     var index = 0;
     using var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(16, 16);
     foreach (var items in FileSearcher.EnumerateFilesRecursively(@"E:/nestedAAAA", batchSize, cancellationToken))
     {
         await semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
         try
         {
             var localIndex = index;
             tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
             {
                 _logger.LogInformation($"[Task {localIndex}] has started.....");
           
                 

                 _logger.LogInformation($"[Task {localIndex}] is done.....");
                 semaphore.Release();
             }, cancellationToken));
             index++;
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             semaphore.Release();
             _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in HarvestEngine RunAsync");
         }
     }

     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
 }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `new SemaphoreSlim(8, 16)`? Why not `new SemaphoreSlim(8, 8)` or `new SemaphoreSlim(16, 16)`?

Comment: Are you targeting the .NET 6 or later? In that case you have the option to use the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it would normally be set to new SemaphoreSlim(16, 16) (Or rather Environment.ProcessorCount) but i was just playing with the number to see how the different tasks would start up and i ended at 8 when i made the post.

And yes im aware of Parallel.ForEachAsync

Thanks for the comments!

Comment: With the `new SemaphoreSlim(8, 16)` you are confusing everyone, because we don't know what your intentions are. Do you want to limit the concurrency to 8 or 16? I would suggest to edit the question and put the same value to both the `initalCount` and `maxCount` parameters, to eliminate this confusion. Also if you have the option stick with the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`. You are trying to reinvent it, and you are doing it wrong. The `List<T>` is not thread-safe, and you are interacting with it from multiple threads without synchronization. As such, the behavior of your code is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StartTasksAsync` is synchronous until the first `await` that *isn't itself* synchronous; which in your case, isn't until *after* the `foreach`.

If your intent is for these to actually run in the background, you could:

1. add an `await Task.Yield();` at the *start* of the method, to force it to become truly async earlier
2. use `Task.Run` when *invoking* the method, taking care around any captured variables (so that you pass in the intended values, not the values at some future time when the callback gets invoked)

The second is more explicit re background, but either should work

---

Additionally:

- the semaphore only seems to protect `tasks`, but that method is the only thing accessing `tasks`, so no protection should be necessary - IMO remove the semaphore completely
- you are removing things from `tasks` before they're completed; IMO remove the `Remove`

If the intention of the semaphore is that you want a fixed number of things running concurrently: maybe use `Parallel.ForEach` instead, using `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Currently trying to refactor based on your solutions.

The semaphore was only used to control the count of running tasks, so i didnt create 1000's of tasks in 1 go. Then later on create a way to control that semaphore concurrent number, so i can get a different service to be prioritized  (But thats gonna me a problem for later)

Im a bit unsure if Parallel.ForEach will be a good solution for my problem as i want to control how many it can run concurrently.

Comment: @uk3ndt `Parallel.ForEach` allows you to control that, by passing in a `ParallelOptions` with the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`

Comment: I wanted to control while it was running. Fx these scans can take a long time, and i have a service that needs to get executed on a fix interval, so i wanted to decrease the scan to prioritize my fixed interval service. fx just decrease it with 2 counts, so there is a good overhead for the fixed service. But im guessing i cant do that with the Parallel if it has to be init with the ParallelOptions?

Comment: I have also updated my post with some of your suggestions. If you are willing to check it out, can you tell why im having problems with writing my logs out to console from my tasks?

After doing some of your recomendations, i have gotten it to print
 [12:31:55 INF] [Task 1] has started.....
[12:31:55 INF] [Task 2] has started.....
[12:31:55 INF] [Task 3] has started.....
And then some of the logging from the tasks itself, so it seems to start multiple up concurrently. But as my post says it prints the first item in the collections it gets passed except on the last task where it prints al

Comment: @uk3ndt you don't need "both" - if you're using `Task.Run`, the `Task.Yield()` is unnecessary; more importantly, look back at my text where I said about "captured variables" - `index` is a captured variable; you're now sharing it between all the tasks (there is only one `index` !) - you need to fix that - the simplest way would be inside the loop but outside the lambda, have `var localIndex = index; // snapshot`, now use `localIndex` inside the lambda instead of `index` - this is now scoped as a snapshot value

Comment: Ahhh, i see what you mean! Your solutions has fixed the main issue and some other problems + given me good insight, thanks!

Comment: The `await Task.Yield()` is a bad suggestion, as discussed in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558319/async-function-not-launching-asynchronously/74558485#74558485 "Async function not launching asynchronously").

Comment: yes i also removed it from my code, just forgot to update post. Thanks for the read!